# Preventing WebBrowser control to refresh with focus

Tags: vba, focus, webbrowser-control, ms-access-2007

I'm working on an Access 2007 database and I'm experiencing some unwanted behavior with the ActiveX WebBrowser control. The control is located on an individual tab of a multi-tab control on the form. When the form loads, I pass it a URL of a page to load.

The form loads fine and so does the webpage. Here's where the unwanted behavior begins. If I switch to a different tab on my form, and switch back, the webbrowser control re-loads the web page. I don't want this. I'm displaying a live map (like Google Maps) that I want to preserve the state it was left.

You can test this by adding the webbrowser control to a tab on a form with a multiple tabs. Point the webbrowser control to a URL like this:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

When the form (and page) loads, move the map, zoom in a few levels. Switch tabs and switch back. The map will reload to its original view. Can I stop this from happening??

This really kills the utlity of what I'm trying to accomplish. THANKS!

Steve

Comment: Sounds similar to a bug in excel VBA whereby a webbrowser in a multipage tab control works once, then dissapears forever. The solution there is to put the browser on the form so its not inside the tab but on top of it, then use the tab change event to show/hide it as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Alex. Unfortunately for me, this didn't change anything. It still produces the same behavior.

Comment: Are you sure the browser it outside the tab control? I tried before I suggested & it worked ok for me (access 2k7)

Comment: Yes, positive. I deleted and re-added the control to be sure. It still re-loads the navigated page. Are there any other properties you've specified with your control? I'm using Win7 64-bit if that makes any difference..

Answer (score 2):

Alex-

I figured out a workaround. The answer was along the lines of your suggestion, which was to remove the webcontrol from the multipage tab. What I ended up doing was create a blank form with only the webcontrol on it. After the form was created, I added it back onto my tab as a subform and it *FINALLY* behaved! I can now switch tabs on the form and the webpage does not re-load.

Hallelujah!